# std::binary_function - no match for call?

Tags: c++, stl

## include

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  binary_function<double, double, double> operations[] = {
    plus<double>(), minus<double>(), multiplies<double>(), divides<double>() 
  };
  double a, b;
  int choice;
  cout << "Enter two numbers" << endl;
  cin >> a >> b;
  cout << "Enter opcode: 0-Add 1-Subtract 2-Multiply 3-Divide" << endl;
  cin >> choice;
  cout << operations[choice](a, b) << endl;
}
```

and the error I am getting is:

```
Calcy.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Calcy.cpp:17: error: no match for call to ‘(std::binary_function<double, double, double>) (double&, double&)’
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::binary_function` only contains typedefs for argument and return types. It was never intended to act as a polymorphic base class (and even if it was, you'd still have problems with slicing).

As an alternative, you can use `boost::function` (or `std::tr1::function`) like this:

```
boost::function<double(double, double)> operations[] = {
  plus<double>(), minus<double>(), multiplies<double>(), divides<double>() 
};
```

Comment: Why doesn't the compiler flag an error on the first line of `main()`? If that array definition is allowed, so should be the calls to the functions stored in the array. Why that error then?

Comment: It just does what you require it to do. `binary_function` (or for what matters any other type in the standard library) don't deserve special treatment from the compiler. Since `plus`... do inherit from `binary_function` the assignment is correct and you get slicing. The compiler fails to compile the last line as `double operator()(double,double)` is not defined in `binary_function`, just as calling any method added in a derived class through a base would fail...

Comment: @David: Alright, I understood it now. Thanks. Post it as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Just accept this one. It is complete and if more detail is needed people can just read the comments (that you can also 'upvote' to make them more visible)