# Usage vector of binary_function. Error: no match for call to ‘(std::binary_function<int, int, int>) (int&, int&)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a `vector` of `binary_function` for a `transform()` call, but I get an error in g++:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 10, 23, 13};
    vector<int> v2 = {10, 2, 4, -1, 3};
    vector<int> result(v1.size());

    plus<int> f1;
    minus<int> f2;
    multiplies<int> f3;

    vector<binary_function<int, int, int>> funcs = {f1, f2, f3};

    for (auto func: funcs) {
        transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), result.begin(), func);
        
        for (auto value: result) { cout << value << " "; }
        cout << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:62,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_OIter std::transform(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _OIter, _BinaryOperation) [with _IIter1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _IIter2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _OIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _BinaryOperation = std::binary_function<int, int, int>]’:
test.cpp:19:67:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:4343:25: error: no match for call to ‘(std::binary_function<int, int, int>) (int&, int&)’
  *__result = __binary_op(*__first1, *__first2);
              ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I read [std::binary_function - no match for call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567980/stdbinary-function-no-match-for-call), but I can't understand the answer:

> std::binary_function only contains typedefs for argument and return types. It was never intended to act as a polymorphic base class (and even if it was, you'd still have problems with slicing).

Why am I getting the error and how to fix it?

Comment: As explained in the linked post, you can use `std::function<int(int, int)>` in your case (requires `#include <functional>`).

Comment: Don't write code by guessing what things do. Read the description of [`std::binary_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function).

Comment: Ok, looks like this is an answer: `std::binary_function does not define operator(); it is expected that derived classes will define this.` Thanks, Pete Becker.

Comment: Remember that `std::binary_function` was deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17. I'd advise not to use it in new code and remove/replace it in old code as eventually you'll have to anyway when you move to C++17 or later.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::binary_function` is not a callable object and it cannot be used directly in the transform function. `std::binary_function` is an outdated class and is not intended for direct use in C++11 and later.

In C++11 and later, you can use function objects to achieve the same result:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 10, 23, 13};
    vector<int> v2 = {10, 2, 4, -1, 3};
    vector<int> result(v1.size());

    plus<int> f1;
    minus<int> f2;
    multiplies<int> f3;

    vector<function<int(int, int)>> funcs = {f1, f2, f3};

    for (auto func: funcs) {
        transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), result.begin(), func);
        
        for (auto value: result) { cout << value << " "; }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[See also [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function).]

Answer (score -2):

Replace the instances of std::binary_function. This should work as expected without any compilation errors.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 10, 23, 13};
    vector<int> v2 = {10, 2, 4, -1, 3};
    vector<int> result(v1.size());

    auto f1 = [](int a, int b) { return a + b; };
    auto f2 = [](int a, int b) { return a - b; };
    auto f3 = [](int a, int b) { return a * b; };

    vector<decltype(f1)> funcs = {f1, f2, f3};

    for (auto func : funcs) {
        transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), result.begin(), func);

        for (auto value : result) {
            cout << value << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to compile this? Because this is not correct code.

Comment: The `f1`..`f3` lambdas have different and unrelated types, so you can't store them together in a `vector` using `decltype(f1)`. You will have to store them using either `std::function<int(int,int)>` or `int(*)(int, int)` instead.